# Is "export" needed, when setting a variable in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, variables, export

I wonder if there is a need to use "export" when setting a variable in .bashrc.

In my tests editing .bashrc there was no difference between

```
foo=bar
```

and

```
export foo=bar
```

In both cases, after login "echo $foo" outputs "bar".

I am using Debian Squeeze, if that matters.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try creating a shell script that accesses the `foo` variable.

If `foo` was `export`'ed, it will be visible in the shell script, otherwise it won't.

Comment: I've created a test script containing "`echo $foo`". In both cases running the script after login the output was "bar". Am i crazy? Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: How do you run the script? `./script` or `. script`?

Comment: I run the script via ``./script``

Comment: Sorry guys. I don't know what went wrong. But now all works as expected. Thank you very much for all your replys!

Answer (score 13):

SuperUser [has this covered](https://superuser.com/questions/143413/linux-environment-variables/).

Short answer: `export` makes sure the environment variable is set in child processes. If you don't export, it's only available in the same process/interactive session.

Comment: I've created a test script containing "`echo $foo`". In both cases running the script after login the output was "bar". Am i crazy? Can anyone reproduce this?

Answer (score 5):

It's preferable because exported variables get passed to child processes (programs launched from that shell).  Without the export command those variables only apply to the shell itself and not processes launched from the shell