# Bash command works in interactive shell but not in script

Tags: linux, bash

Ohai,
got another Bash problem.

```
for i in ${#input}; do echo ${input:$i:1}; done
```

works in the interactive bash, but not in a shell script. Input is a variable, based on an argument. It's set properly.
Any ideas?

Comment: One of your statements is false.

Comment: Might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297271/bash-is-export-needed-when-setting-a-variable-in-bashrc/6297339#6297339

Comment: is the first line of your script `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how it is working in interactive shell for you, this expression:

```
${#input}
```

- will return number of characters in the first element if `input` is array variable 

  **otherwise**
- will return number of characters in the `input` variable

**EDIT:** based on your comments

I think you are trying to do this code:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#input}; i++))
do
   echo ${input:$i:1}
done
```

This code will iterate for each character in input string and then echo each character.

Comment: But what is `$i` in this case? As per your code for loop will execute only once.

Comment: @thkala: lol :) I wish I had such power. But `for i in ${#input};` made no sense and as per his code it just appeared to me perhaps he/she's trying to print input string character by character (of course I may be completely wrong).

Comment: Yep, that's what I try to do. $i is the counter of a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the purpose of this piece of code - it's equivalent to a single `echo`.

Explanation:

`${#input}` is the length of the contents of the `input` variable. It is *always* a single number, hence the loop will *always* be executed *once*. `$i` is then modified to contain that variable length.

Then `${input:$i:1}` means "1 character from the `input` variable, starting at offset `$i`, which is equal to the length of the variable, and, therefore, past its end. I.e. `${input:$i:1}` is always an empty string. So your code can be simplified to:

`echo`

As an example, if `$input` is `foobar`, then `${#input}` is `6`, and your loop executes *once* this command: `echo ${input:6:1}`. Offsets here are zero-based, therefore `6` is just past the last character of `$input`. If you are trying to get the last character of a variable, try this:

```
$ input=foobar; echo ${input:${#input}-1:1}
r
```

What exactly are you trying to do?